# Bash quotes disable escaping

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, escaping

I want to run some command, let's name it "test" from my bash script and put there some of params from bash variable.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PARAMS="-A 'Foo' -B 'Bar'"
./test $PARAMS
```

I've got:

```
+ PARAMS='-A '\''Foo'\'' -B '\''Bar'\'''
+ ./test -A ''\''Foo'\''' -B ''\''Bar'\'''
```

It's wrong!

Another one case:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PARAMS='-A '"'"'Foo'"'"' -B '"'"'Bar'"'"
./test $PARAMS
```

Result is sad too:

```
+ PARAMS='-A '\''Foo'\'' -B '\''Bar'\'''
+ ./test -A ''\''Foo'\''' -B ''\''Bar'\'''
```

So, question is – how can I use bash variable as command line arguments for some command.
Variable is something like "-A 'Foo' -B 'Bar'" (exactly with single-quotes)
And result must be calling of program "./test" with arguments "-A 'Foo' -B 'Bar'" like this:

```
./test -A 'Foo' -B 'Bar'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Probably I must put some parameter to #!/bin/bash like "-x" that I added to see raw commands.

Comment: If you just echo your first one it is in the right format. `-x` just shows how bash sees it not your script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is safer to use BASH arrays for storing full or partial command lines like this:

```
params=(-A 'Foo' -B 'Bar')
```

then call it as:

```
./test "${params[@]}"
```

which will be same as:

```
./test -A 'Foo' -B 'Bar'
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: @IvanPomortsev Not only is it safer, it's precisely the reason arrays exist in shells.